# Illustrating the relationship between Ellipticity of Differential Operators and Coordinate Changes

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reading *Einstein Manifolds* (Besse).  At the end of Section 5F, the author states (paraphrasing slightly):

> "One may have been confused that the Ricci equation $\text{Ric}(g) = r$ and the Einstein equation $\text{Ric}(g) = \lambda g$ are elliptic in certain coordinates, but not in others (whereas, "the definition of "elliptic" is invariant under changes of coordinates").
>
> This is resolved by observing that in changing coordinates for these equations, one not only changes the independent variables, but also one is making a change in the dependent variables as well, since the metric $g$ is a tensor field and hence is transformed, too.  The statement that "ellipticity is invariant" refers only to changes of independent variables."

I only grasp these two paragraphs on a hazy, vague level.  To gain a better understanding, I would like to see **a simpler example that explicitly illustrates** how "changing the independent variables" versus "changing the dependent variables" affects (or doesn't affect) the ellipticity of the equation.

I would be especially interested in seeing this illustrated with, say, the Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ for functions $u \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, or the harmonic map system $\Delta \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ for functions $\mathbf{u} \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$, or the Cauchy-Riemann system $u_x = v_y$, $u_y = -v_x$ for functions $(u,v) \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

This question is closely related to this [very nice one by juan rojo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855259/ellipticity-of-ricci-tensor-does-it-depend-on-coordinates) and also to one that I [asked a while ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278328/why-are-diffeomorphism-invariant-pde-not-elliptic).